SQL and Management Nodes on same server in NDB cluster. SQL Nodes not connecting
I've setup a ndb cluster with 7 nodes. 3 data nodes on their own servers, and 2 management nodes that each have a sql node on them on 2 servers.
I've narrowed down what I think my issue is. My cluster seems to be unable to elect a president data node, but I have no idea how to set the election rules. Can anyone help me with my setup? Is my config wrong?
Thanks.
Below is all the details.
Here is my management node config:
[ndbd default]
NoOfReplicas=3
#DataMemory=2048M
#IndexMemory=512M
 
#Management Nodes
[ndb_mgmd]
hostname=192.168.0.1
NodeId=1
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster
 
[ndb_mgmd]
hostname=192.168.0.2
NodeId=2
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster
 
#Data Nodes
[ndbd]
hostname=192.168.0.3
NodeId=3
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data
 
[ndbd]
hostname=192.168.0.4
NodeId=4
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data
 
[ndbd]
hostname=192.168.0.5
NodeId=5
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data
 
#front end servers
[mysqld]
hostname=192.168.0.1
#NodeId=11
 
[mysqld]
hostname=192.168.0.2
#NodeId=22

Here is my sql node config - my.cnf
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

[mysqld]
ndbcluster

[mysql_cluster]
ndb-connectstring=192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2

Here is the data node connection string
[mysql_cluster]
# Options for NDB Cluster processes:
ndb-connectstring=192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2

This is what ndb_mgm> show is saying
id=3    @192.168.0.3  (mysql-8.3.0 ndb-8.3.0, starting, Nodegroup: 0)
id=4    @192.168.0.4  (mysql-8.3.0 ndb-8.3.0, starting, Nodegroup: 0)
id=5    @192.168.0.5  (mysql-8.3.0 ndb-8.3.0, starting, Nodegroup: 0)

[ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 2 node(s)
id=1    @192.168.0.1  (mysql-8.3.0 ndb-8.3.0)
id=2    @192.168.0.2  (mysql-8.3.0 ndb-8.3.0)

[mysqld(API)]   2 node(s)
id=6 (not connected, accepting connect from 192.168.0.1)
id=7 (not connected, accepting connect from 192.168.0.2)

Nodes 3,4, & 5 are stuck in status
ndb_mgm> 3 status
Node 3: starting (Last completed phase 0) (mysql-8.3.0 ndb-8.3.0)

ndb_mgm> 4 status
Node 4: starting (Last completed phase 0) (mysql-8.3.0 ndb-8.3.0)

ndb_mgm> 5 status
Node 5: starting (Last completed phase 0) (mysql-8.3.0 ndb-8.3.0)

SQL Nodes 6 (11) & 7 (22) will not connect.
SQL & Data Nodes have nothing in their error logs.
The cluster log for the management nodes have this on repeat every minute:
TIME [MgmtSrvr] INFO     -- Alloc node id 6 rejected, no new president yet
TIME [MgmtSrvr] WARNING  -- Unable to allocate nodeid for API at 192.168.0.1. Returned error: 'Cluster not ready for nodeid allocation.'
TIME [MgmtSrvr] INFO     -- Node 3: Initial start, waiting for 4 and 5 to connect,  nodes [ all: 3, 4 and 5 connected: 3 no-wait:  ]
TIME [MgmtSrvr] INFO     -- Node 5: Initial start, waiting for 3 and 4 to connect,  nodes [ all: 3, 4 and 5 connected: 5 no-wait:  ]
TIME [MgmtSrvr] INFO     -- Node 4: Initial start, waiting for 3 and 5 to connect,  nodes [ all: 3, 4 and 5 connected: 4 no-wait:  ]


It sounds like the data nodes can not connect to each other, perhaps firewalls are in use?
Since data nodes have been able to connect to the management server the port 1186 is opened in the firewall.
But all MySQL servers and data nodes will also connect to all data nodes, and by default data nodes listen on dynamically allocated ports which are published to the other nodes via management server. This mode of operation is not suitable for firewalls.
When using firewalls also on data node hosts one need to configure which port the data node should listen on and open that port in the firewall.
The data node listening port is configured by ServerPort parameter. For example:
# config.ini
[ndbd default]
ServerPort=1187
...

Change that and restart all management servers, remember using --reload when restarting the first management server but not for the other.
Make sure that the selected data node listening port is open in firewall. And then restart all data nodes.
The MySQL servers will show as connected to ndb_mgm when they have managed to connect to the data nodes.

That was the problem. Thank you.

Good to here @Mr.Berzerk. Please accept the answer, we both gain reputation that way.
